# Filter objects inside array in MySQL JSON column

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-5.7

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and I have a simple table with two columns: `id` and `json`. And I want to filter rows using objects inside an array within `json` column.

Here's an example of a `json` content:

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "items": [{
            "price": 5,
            "item": {
                "name": "Item One"
            }
        },
        {
            "price": 10,
            "item": {
                "name": "Item Two"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to filter based on `items.price` and `items.item.name`.

I was able to filter using JSON_CONTENTS like this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json, '{"price": 5}', '$.items')`

AND

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(json, '{"item": {"name": "Item One"}}', '$.items')`

However this only works when I'm looking for `price EQUALS 5` and `name EQUALS "Item One"`.

I need to find, for instance, `price IS GREATER THAN 1` and I was not able to do so. I tried this:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE json->"$.items.price" > 1`

But it doesn't work. When I use the where clause like this `json->"$.items[0].price" > 1` it works, but it only consider the first array position.

I even tried this `json->"$.items[*].price" > 1` but it returns an empty result.

I'm considering create another table, only with the `items`. But if there is a way to filter the original table would be much simpler.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Upgrade your server to 8+ version and use JSON_TABLE().

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using JSON if it makes this simple query so difficult? Why not store the array as rows of a second table? Then the query would be easy.

Comment: This database is used to extract some reports. The original database is quite complex and takes too much to generate simple reports. I used this idea and worked pretty well in simple JSONs, but for this specific one I faced this problem. Unfortunately, I'm unable to upgrade to 8+, so I'll probably store these arrays as rows on a second table as you said.